# Update multiple ids in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to update data to multiple ids, I take all ids

**controller**

```
    public function getIds(){
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['std_id']);$i++){
        echo $_POST['std_id'][$i];
        $student_id[]=$_POST['std_id'][$i];
    }
```

I don't know how to update this?

How to write the modal function?

Comment: ok so you want to pass `id` array to mysql `IN(id1,id2,id3)` query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to create separate array for that. You can pass `$_POST['std_id]` which is having array of `id`s.

**controller**

```
$this->modelname->mymethod($_POST['std_id'],$updateData);
```

where `$_POST['std_id']` is an array of ids and `$updateData` for updating fields

**model**

```
function mymethod($idArr,$data){
    $this->db->where_in("fieldname", $idArr);
    $this->db->update("tablename",$data);
}
```

you can use `where_in` for mysql `IN` to check multiple ids.